# How to attach pre-uploaded SSL cert to ELB in CloudFormation template?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, portforwarding, aws-cloudformation

I've been trying to attach a SSL certificate that I'm currently using for one of my Elastic Load Balancing Instances on a new Cloud Formation Template but each time I get:
 *Server Certificate not found for the key*
And then the Cloudformation template starts to roll back at that point.

```
            "Listeners" : [ 
         {
          "LoadBalancerPort" : "443",
          "InstancePort" : "80",
          "SSLCertificateId" : "start_certname_com",
          "Protocol" : "HTTPS"
         },...
```

Amazon is asking for the *The ARN of the SSL certificate to use.* and I believe this is correct since this is the exact string which appears in the dropdown of the current set up ELB which takes 443 to port 80 on the instances.

Am I missing something on my Listener?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've actually figured out how to do this while waiting for the answer, you need to use the IAM CLI tools provided by amazon and then use the command
`iam-servercertgetattributes -s certname`

This will provide you a string like:

`arn:aws:iam::123456789123:server-certificate/start_certname_com`

This is the value you place in the "SSLCertificateId" value pair field

The setup instructions for the IAM command line tools (CLI) can be found  at:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/CLIReference/Setup.html

Download the tool kit from aws here
http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/AWS-Identity-and-Access-Management/4143

All in all your final block will look like:

```
 "Listeners" : [ 
    {  
      "LoadBalancerPort" : "443",  
      "InstancePort" : "80",  
      "SSLCertificateId" : "arn:aws:iam::123456789123:server-certificate/start_certname_com",  
      "Protocol" : "HTTPS"  
     },...
```

Comment: Great follow up answer - helped a lot.

Comment: It is also possible do this lookup directly in cloud formation.  See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=248285.

Comment: Tristan's answer is well-explained by @gene_wood in is answer below.

Comment: I am using Troposphere to create cloudformation stack, 
```Listener = t.add_resource(elb.Listener(
    "Listener",
    Certificates=elb.Certificate(
        CertificateArn="",
    ),
    Port="443",
    Protocol="HTTPS",
    LoadBalancerArn=Ref(ApplicationLoadBalancer),
    SslPolicy="ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-Ext-2018-06",
    DefaultActions=[elb.Action(
        Type="forward",
        TargetGroupArn=Ref(TargetGroupApp)
    )]
))```

what is need to be added in `certificatearn`

Answer (score 33):

You can derive the [ARN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) for a certificate in CloudFormation with only the certificate name. No need to run a command line tool and hard code the value into your CloudFormation template.

```
    "Parameters":{
      "Path":{
         "Description":"AWS Path",
         "Default":"/",
         "Type":"String"
      }
    }
     ...
        "Listeners" : [ 
     {
      "LoadBalancerPort" : "443",
      "InstancePort" : "80",
      "SSLCertificateId" : {
        "Fn::Join":[
           "",
           [
              "arn:aws:iam::",
              {
                 "Ref":"AWS::AccountId"
              },
              ":server-certificate",
              {
                 "Ref":"Path"
              },
              "start_certname_com"
           ]
        ]
      },
      "Protocol" : "HTTPS"
     },...
```

This determines your account id with the `{"Ref":"AWS::AccountId"}` [pseudo parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html) and [combines](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) it with the other elements needed to form the [ARN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html). Note that I'm using a variable called `Path` in case you've set a path for your certificate. If not the default of "/" works fine.

This solution was mentioned by @Tristan and is an extension of [merrix143243's solution](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=266686#266914)

Comment: Definitely the best answer!

Comment: Very cool! If anyone's using [cloudformation-ruby-dsl](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/cloudformation-ruby-dsl), here's a one-liner inspired by this answer:
`:SSLCertificateId => join('', 'arn:aws:iam::', aws_account_id(), ':server-certificate/', ref('SSLCertificateName'))`

Comment: @gene_wood The answer fits Amazon-issued certificates, but perhaps not the ones that I imported (from other certification authorities). The imported ones get assigned a GUID as visible in the "Identifier" field in ACM (Amazon Certificate Management). Also, in march 2018, 1) the "arn:aws:acm::" seems to be the prefix not ":iam::", 2) the ":server-certificate" looks like ":certificate" (unless I imported it wrong). Question: which field in ACM does your "start_certname_com" correspond to: "Domain name", "Additional names", "Identifier", "Name" (user tag)?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you get the long cert name with the latest AWS CLI:

```
pip install awscli
aws iam list-server-certificates
```